# Excel 2010 connecting to SQL Server Database from within Cell Function?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have already used the Data -> Get Data From External Sources -> From Other Sources -> SQL Server.

This only imports a live copy of the table I would like.

What I would love to be able to do is execute an SQL statement from within a cell. Is this possible at all?

Comment: Need more info, do you mean pull data into a single cell?  If so simply write a macro in excel and set the cell value to the results of the pulled data.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  I'm trying to avoid adding a worksheet and doing a VLOOKUP on the new worksheet. I'd rather just get my single cell data directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import allows you to copy views as well as tables.  So you could create a view that returns a value:

```
create view dbo.vw_ExcelCellA3 as
    select TheColumn from YourTable where id = 1
```

This way, you can place any SQL "behind" a cell.

Comment: Would this still allow me to reference other cells to complete the view?

Comment: If the imported cell is `B4`, you can reference it in another cell to complete the computation, like `=B4+2`.  One typical approach would be to move the imported cells to a "computation" sheet.

Comment: Looks like what I want isn't going to happen.  Thanks though!